# Latest and complete list of mobile user agents string

Tags: java, mobile, user-agent

As I want to detect mobile devices based on User Agent Header String, where can I get the references of the complete and latest list of those User Agents String? As for now, I found bits and pieces.

Comment: Given some browsers do (or at least did) allow the user to configure it themselves, I'd say a RegEx that detects any legal character for a UA string should do the job.  BTW - it is usually unnecessary to ask a visitor what browser they use.  What feature are you attempting to offer by doing so?

Comment: I want to detect the user's browser, so I can differentiate between mobile version website and desktop version website. Moreover, for the mobile version site, I need to make necessary adjustments according to what kind of mobile device that user is using. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

maybe this might help? 
http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can - they change too often and too quickly. Try instead using a service like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net) or [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com) that will parse the User Agent for you and return the properties of the phone (screen size, browser capabilities etc).  The likes of WURLF and DeviceAtlas take care of updating their databases of phone user agents.

Comment: The wurfl user-agents are normalized, i.e. some details have been left out.

Comment: The WURFL database hasn't been updated since November 8 2012. As a result it's missing things like the Blackberry Z10 and HTC One.